# How to route to default and use the remaining url string as a parameter on the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, routes

I am still new to node.js and express. I want to use specific parts of the URL as parameters for the client-side JS.

For example, consider the folling urls and what they should lead to

- example.com/api/foo (API calls)
- example.com (index.html)
- example.com/images/cat.gif (specific file)
- example.com/something/bar (the tricky one!)
- example.com/baz (the same)

Now the last two should actually serve the static **index.html as with *example.com* and allow me to pass the "something/bar" (or "baz") as a parameter the index.html can use for javascript in the browser**.

It does not matter how I get the parameter there (using window.location or adding an attribute like ), I just want to use it. I do *not* want to use GET parameter like

- example.com?id=something/bar

My express app.js uses routing like this:

```
app.use('/backend', require('./routes/backend')) // an example routing path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))) // existing files like images, JS and CSS
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // error handling
});
```

I have tried something like

```
app.get('*:path',function (req, res) {
  let parameter = req.path // this I could use somehow
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

But this redirects to /. I suppose I could use it to send a non-static index.html with that, but it would still change the url that is shown. Preferably, I would still like to be able to use relative urls in my HTML/CSS.

I am not even this is the right approach to my problem so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/:something/:bar', function(req, res) {

    let something_value = req.params.something;
    let bar_value = req.params.bar;

    //console.log(`The parameters are ${something_value} ${bar_value}`);

    //do something         

    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Here you would have to go to url like **http ://example.com/something/bar**.

Comment: Thanks. But I was hoping for a general solution that would not have me define all the possibilities.

Comment: @Avark there are few other ways to do that but I don't think you can define all possibilities. Other way is to send an json object like {"something":"value","bar":"value"} to the params.

Comment: Also I'm confused do you want to send these from server to client or a request from client to server via route?

Comment: I'm trying to send it to the client, but "ignoring" it on the server.
//example.com/ should be the same as //example.com/something/bla/ for the server, but not for the client. Basically, I am making async requests on the client anyway, but i want to create clean, rest-style urls